# Find() and First() throws exceptions, how to return null instead?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, lambda

Is there a linq lambda search method that returns null, instead of throwing an exception, when searching a list?

My current solution is something like: (to avoid exception from being thrown)

```
if (list.Exists(x => x.Foo == Foo))
{
    var listItem = list.Find(x => x.Foo == Foo);
}
```

It just feels wrong to repeat the expression.

Something like ...

```
var listItem = list.Find(x => x.Foo == Foo);
if (listItem != null)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

... feels better to me. Or is it just me?

Do you have a better approach on this one? (The solution don't have to be returning null, just a better solution is good)

Comment: Did the behaviour of List<T>.Find change? Current versions of the .Net are allowing the second example. Was List<T>.Find throwing in older verions of the .Net Framework if no matching element was found?

Answer (score 156, accepted):

```
var listItem = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Foo == Foo);
if (listItem != null)
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect the List is of reference types as opposed to value types.. I hesitated to write the comment on such an old, highly up voted, highly viewed question.    For ex: if list contains objects that are classes, list item will return a default(instance of class), i.e. new'ed up class which will not be null!  See [Bazzz's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613443/find-and-first-throws-exceptions-how-to-return-null-instead#answer-5613548) answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5613443/find-and-first-throws-exceptions-how-to-return-null-instead#answer-5613548

Answer (score 61):

Bala R's answer is correct, I just wanted to add a piece of information:

Note that if `List<T>` contains objects that by-design cannot be null, the `FirstOrDefault` will return something else than `null`. The compiler is likely to give a warning/error of this at the if statement. In that case you should approach your situation like this:

```
List<MyObjectThatCannotBeNull> list;
var listItem = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Foo == Foo);
if (!listItem.Equals(default(MyObjectThatCannotBeNull)))
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: and don't forget - if your list will contain the default value for that generic type ([Default Values Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)), you cannot tell if the value exist or not using `Find` method. You should use `FindIndex`, `Exists` or `Contains` in those situations.

Answer (score 1):

##### `Find` do not trow exception but unless the predicate is null.

You can use the "is" operator :)

```
  List<T> list = new List<T>();
  if (list.Find(x => x.Foo == Foo) is T yourObject)
  {
     //do stuff with yourObject.
  }
```

`Find`return the first element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, if found; otherwise, the default value for type T.

So You can have the same result with FirstOrDefault

```
  List<T> list;
  if (list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Foo == Foo) is T yourObject)
  {
     //do stuff with yourObject.
  }
```